# Polars dataframe sorting based on absolute value of a column

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I would like to sort a polars dataframe based on absolute value of a column in either ascending or descending order. It is easy to do in `Pandas`, or using `sorted` function in python. Let's say I want to sort based on `val` column in the below dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "name": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two", "two"],
    "id": ["C", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"],
    "val": np.random.randint(-10, 10, 6)
    })
```

Returns:

```
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ name ┆ id  ┆ val │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str ┆ i32 │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ one  ┆ C   ┆ -4  │
│ one  ┆ A   ┆ 9   │
│ one  ┆ B   ┆ 4   │
│ two  ┆ B   ┆ 0   │
│ two  ┆ C   ┆ -3  │
│ two  ┆ C   ┆ -4  │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to sort based on the absolute value of `'val'`?

Expressions are your friend, no need for temporary columns:

```py
In [33]: df.sort(pl.col('val').abs())
Out[33]:
shape: (6, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ name ┆ id  ┆ val │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ two  ┆ B   ┆ 0   │
│ two  ┆ C   ┆ -3  │
│ one  ┆ C   ┆ -4  │
│ one  ┆ B   ┆ 4   │
│ two  ┆ C   ┆ -4  │
│ one  ┆ A   ┆ 9   │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: That's indeed easy ;) How would you sort by the absolute value and by another column left unchanged?

Comment: you can pass multiple arguments to `sort`, e.g. `.sort(pl.col('val').abs(), 'id', 'price')`

Answer (score 0):

You could always add a temporary column with the absolute values (using [`with_columns`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_columns.html) and `abs`), [`sort`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.sort.html), then [`drop`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.drop.html) it:

```
df.with_columns(abs=pl.col('val').abs()).sort('abs').drop('abs')
```

Output:

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┐
│ name ┆ id  ┆ val │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ str ┆ i64 │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╡
│ two  ┆ B   ┆ 0   │
│ two  ┆ C   ┆ -3  │
│ one  ┆ C   ┆ -4  │
│ one  ┆ B   ┆ 4   │
│ two  ┆ C   ┆ -4  │
│ one  ┆ A   ┆ 9   │
└──────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: @beta_green have you seen the other answer? This seems like a straightforward approach ;)